# Getting "Ambiguous input redirect." when using diff

Tags: debian, diff

I'm relatively new to linux so be tender.

```
diff shiftingV1.0 < inputTest.in shiftingV1.2 < inputTest.in
```

Basically I want to check if there's any difference between the output of those two (written in C) for a given input, I can write the output of each code to a txt and then compare but I think this is a better solution, but it's not really working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If `shiftingV1.0` and `shiftingV1.2` are commands that produce their output on the standard output stream, then you can use bash's *process substitution* feature, e.g.

```
diff <(command1) <(command2)
```

or in your case, assuming your commands read from the file `inputTest.in` via standard input

```
diff <(shiftingV1.0 < inputTest.in) <(shiftingV1.2 < inputTest.in)
```